# smarty string_format doesn't round up

Tags: smarty

Based on the documentation of [string_format](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl)

This:

```
{$testy = 16.99}{$testy|string_format:'%d'}
```

Should output `17` but it gives me `16` instead

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an error in the new documentation.
If you look at the [old version](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl) it is correct.

In cases you need `17` I recommend this:

```
{$testy|ceil|string_format:"%d"}
```